# alpine.k ajax form post to laravel route

Tags: ajax, laravel, alpine.js

I have a function that sends a form post with data to my Laravel application.

```
async handleDataSend(dsCommand, dsData) {

    console.log(dsCommand);
    console.log(dsData);

    dat = {};

    await (await fetch('{{ route('alpineDataSend') }}', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            command: dsCommand,
            data: dsData
        }),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
    })).json();

    return dat;

    },
```

My route is very basic right now.

```
Route::post('/alpineDataSend', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request->all());
}->name("alpineDataSend");
```

I see the form data in the form post using the inspector in the browser.

```
{"command":"saveCountyStateCityData","data":{"country_key":"US","state_key":3922,"city_key":42752}}
```

The problem is there is no data being received by the route.

```
[] // routes/web.php:487
```

Am I missing something in the ajax post code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem from another post. I needed to add the json header to the ajax code.

```
async handleDataSend(dsCommand, dsData) {

                    console.log(dsCommand);
                    console.log(dsData);

                    dat = {};

                    await (await fetch('{{ route('alpineDataSend') }}', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            command: dsCommand,
                            data: dsData
                        }),
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        },
                    })).json();

                    return dat;

                    },
```

I now received the data in the route.

```
array:2 [ // routes/web.php:487
  "command" => "saveCountyStateCityData"
  "data" => array:3 [
    "country_key" => "US"
    "state_key" => 3920
    "city_key" => 42671
  ]
]
```